# Issue with compiling contract with OpenZeppelin

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I wrote a simple contract using OpenZeppelin for ownership but I got the error message when trying to compile that ownable.sol won't compile because of the "expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition" error and its highlighting the abstract keyword... what do I do?

I tried checking if the import link connecting ownable.sol to context.sol is correct.I tried `truffle compile -- all`. I also tried removing the abstract keyword but it didn't work at all.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Share your solidity code